# Issue with updating firebase db with date inputs using kendo ui for angular 4

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, datepicker, kendo-ui-angular2

When using Kendo date picker it doesn't seem to like it when I use a model says cannot find $key (apart of my model) when I initiate it in OnInit as per Kendo instructions. I can get datepicker to work in general, but I need it to be apart of a form and added to my database when user submits from, and that's the only piece I can't seem to get working properly.

**Edit**

After doing a bit more experimentation it seems ngModel is binding just fine. I added {{ todo.TaskDate }} underneath the field and as I inputed data my string interpolation updated as expected. It seems the issue is more related to my Firebase Api?

Thoughts as to why:

1. Everything updates to my db asynchronously as expected except for the date and time fields.
2. If I open the edit box to edit the date it then appears on my task card as I would expect. Also to note my edit box isn't yet connected properly to the Api.

I'll update the issue again once I do some more exploring on why my Api doesn't seem to like date inputs.

Answer (score 0):

is the datepicker visible to the component? 
Without code difficult to say?

Maybe try: oninit = () =>{}

Comment: It's visible within my Angular project as I would expect. I can type in all my other data and submit it just fine. I can even select a date in the datepicker without any issues. After this point it does absolutely nothing. In stackblitz example it doesn't display the entire datepicker for some reason, but I get the same error message in both my angular project and stackblitz.

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/oWah  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509523/binding-date-value-to-ng-model-in-angular-kendo-date-picker